# Is this simplification correct? (Demorgans Theorem)

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

```
{a(b+c)+a’b}’
```

using demorgans theorem I got `a'+ b'c'a + b'` then I factored `b'` out of `b'c'a + b'` to get `b'(1+c'a)` which just turns into `b'`. plugging it back into the equation I'm left with `a'+b'`. Is that correct or do I have this all wrong?

Comment: The theorem I learned says that (AC)' = A'+C'.

Comment: The 1 is a result of one of the 12 boolean rules for simplifying expressions. The one I used is A + 1 = 1. Basically anything Or'ed with 1 is equivalent to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
{a(b+c)+(a'b)}' = (a (b+c))' . (a'b)'    
                = (a' + (b+c)') . (a+b')
                = (a' + (b'.c')) . (a+b')
                = (a.a') + (a'b') + (ab'c') + (b'c')
                = 0 + a'b' + b'c'(a+1)
                = a'b' + b'c'(1)
                = a'b' + b'c'
                = b'(a'+c')
```